# Value undefined using then in cypress

Tags: javascript, automation, cypress

Hey guys i keep getting undefined, do i need to somehow create a promise or there is another way around, my value only exist inside a then()  , also i am calling same thing twice is there a nice way of writing this together.

```
it.only('should switch to transaction history second page', () => {
    let firstRowDate;
    let secondRowDate;

    TransactionsPage.tableRows.eq(0).find("td.cdk-cell.date.cdk-column-Date.table-cell").then((value) =>{
      firstRowDate = value.text()
    })
    console.log(firstRowDate) -> undefined

    TransactionsPage.appIconNext.click();

    TransactionsPage.tableRows.eq(0).find("td.cdk-cell.date.cdk-column-Date.table-cell").then((value) =>{
      secondRowDate = value.text()
    })
    console.log(secondRowDate) -> undefined

    cy.url().should('eq', `${Cypress.config().baseUrl}/${Route.TransactionListPage + '?page=2'}`);
    })
  
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to write the console.log inside a `then` to make sure cypress executes the command synchronously

```js
TransactionsPage.tableRows
  .eq(0)
  .find('td.cdk-cell.date.cdk-column-Date.table-cell')
  .then((value) => {
    secondRowDate = value.text()
  })
  .then(() => {
    console.log(secondRowDate)
  })
```

You can use aliases to save values and use them like this:

```js
TransactionsPage.tableRows
  .eq(0)
  .find('td.cdk-cell.date.cdk-column-Date.table-cell')
  .then((value) => {
    cy.wrap(value.text()).as('value')
  })

cy.get('@value').then((value) => {
  //Access value here
})
```

You can do something like this:

```js
it.only('should switch to transaction history second page', () => {
  TransactionsPage.tableRows
    .eq(0)
    .find('td.cdk-cell.date.cdk-column-Date.table-cell')
    .then((value) => {
      cy.wrap(value.text()).as('value1')
    })

  TransactionsPage.appIconNext.click()

  TransactionsPage.tableRows
    .eq(0)
    .find('td.cdk-cell.date.cdk-column-Date.table-cell')
    .then((value) => {
      cy.wrap(value.text()).as('value2')
    })

  //compare values
  cy.get('@value1').then((value1) => {
    cy.get('@value2').then((value2) => {
      expect(value1).to.eq(value2)
    })
  })

  cy.url().should(
    'eq',
    `${Cypress.config().baseUrl}/${Route.TransactionListPage + '?page=2'}`
  )
})
```

Comment: my goal is not that , the issues is that the value is not assigned if i print it ountside the function, so how can i possibly achieve that?

Comment: Also you see i need to call same function twice  so i need value take from each call to make assertion later but now they all undefined

Comment: oh wow, i dont even need to create promises i can just save them to alieses and they be there no matter what, thats amazing thank you so so much

Comment: why do we need to wrap it ? and is it a good practice to call cy get then  and then inside that then another cy.get

Answer (score 0):

You can console log it in the same `.then()`.

```js
TransactionsPage.tableRows.eq(0).find("td.cdk-cell.date.cdk-column-Date.table-cell").then((value) =>{
      secondRowDate = value.text()
      console.log(secondRowDate)
    })
```